# Jquery append() behavior - adding several new elements

Tags: jquery

I have doubt w.r.t jquery append() behavior when adding several elements.

As per below example,
Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function appendText()
{
var text1=$("<a></a>").text("Text1.");  // Create text with jQuery
var text2=$("<a></a>").text("Text2.");  // Create text with jQuery
var text3=$("<p></p>").text("Text3.");  // Create text with jQuery
var text4=$("<p></p>").text("Text4.");  // Create text with jQuery

$("#divTest").append(text1,text2,text3,text4);      // Append new elements

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="appendText()">Append text</button>
<div id="divTest"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

```
Text1.Text2

Text3.

Text4.
```

**Question**

```
1. Why append is adding the anchor tag next to each other? 
2. Why append is  adding the "P" element one after the other?
3. Are there any specific set of elements, for which append() behavior varies?
4. What I was trying with append is to show links one after the other as below.But could'nt.
```

Text1.

Text2.

Text3.

Text4

Note: I have already tried with jquery after() but the behavior is same as append() in above case.

Kindly guide me.

Thanks,

Ashu

Comment: Why are you adding text to <a> tag?

Comment: `<p>` will occupy fill width (100%) so its coming next line but the `<a>` will occupy the text  length only

Comment: try `$("#divTest").append(text1,'<br>',text2,text3,text4);` or `$("#divTest").append(text1,text2,text3,text4).find('a').css('clear','both');`

Comment: Thank you @PranavCBalan your solution helped me. Rahul it is only in example I am adding text, otherwise I will be adding links.Rhyne Thanks for the guidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:
The "a" is an inline tag which will appear on one line unless forced to do so.

Question 2:
The "p" is a block tag which appears on a new line.

Question 3:
I believe there is none.

Question 4:
Try using this:

```
$("#divTest").append(text1, '<br>', text2, text3, text4);
```

Comment: Typo? "unless forced to do so." → "unless forced *not* to do so."?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ayE9n/)

1:By default all `a tag is inline elements`.so it doesn't take linebreak.

2:`P tag default block element` so it take full width and take line break after and before.

3 I don't think so.

4 You can do by changing inline to block in css like in css `a{display:block}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through `Block level` tags and `inline` tags. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

`<div>` `<p>` `<h1>` are some block level tags. on `append()` it will take new line.

whereas `<span>` `<a>` are `inline` tags. on `append()` it will come on same line.

In your case if you require `<a>` tags to be displayed on new line then include a break line tag `<br/>`